# $y_n^*\to y^*$ strongly in $Y^*$ and $y_n\to y$ weakly in $Y$ implies $y_n^*(y_n) \to y^*(y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

given a sequence $y^*_k \in Y^*$ with $\|y^*_k-y^* \| \to 0$.
($y_k \to y$ weakly convergent in $(Y,\| \|_Y)$)

show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n^*(y_n) = y^*(y)$.

My idea:

$|y_n^*(y_n) - y^*(y)| \le |y^*_n(y_n)-y^*_n(y)| +|y^*_n(y)-y^*(y)| \le \| y^*_n \| \|y_n-y\|+|y^*_n(y)-y^*(y)|$

I'm a bit confused here, what can I assume is $y_n$ bounded? $ \|y_n-y\| \to 0$? what about $|y^*_n(y)-y^*(y)|$?
I'm very thankful for tips.

Greetings.

Comment: What is $Y$? What is $y_n$??? Do you think that we know this because you do?

Comment: sorry, just edited.

Comment: Subtract $y^*(y_n)$ instead of $y_n^*(y)$. Also, you still haven't said what $Y$ is although I asked that above!

Comment: Thank you. I dont quite understand why this would be better?

Comment: Y ist just a normed space.

Comment: In a non-complete space tis should be false. You need that $Y$ is a Banach space.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y_n\to y$ weakly, we deduce that $M:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|y_n\|<\infty$ (use the uniform boundedness principle and the canonical isometry from $Y$ into $Y^{**}$ to see this).

Then, for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align*}
|y_n^*(y_n)-y^*(y)|
&\le |y_n^*(y_n)-y_k^*(y_n)|+|y_k^*(y_n)-y^*(y_n)|+|y^*(y_n)-y^*(y)| \\
&\le \|y_n^*-y_k^*\|\|y_n\|+\|y_k^*-y^*\|\|y_n\|+|y^*(y_n)-y^*(y)| \\
&\le M(\|y_n^*-y_k^*\|+\|y_k^*-y^*\|)+|y^*(y_n)-y^*(y)|.
\end{align*}

Now use the facts that $y_n^*\to y^*$ and $y^*(y_n)\to y^*(y)$ to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$$
|y_n^*(y_n) - y^*(y)|\le|(y_n^*- y^*)(y_n)| + |y^*(y_n-y)|\le\|y_n^*-y^*\|\|y_n\| + |y^*(y_n-y)|.
$$
If $Y$ is a Banach space, $(y_n)$ - as a weakly convergent sequence - is bounded. So, both terms tend to zero.